# Не могу вызвать нужный сервлет

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, servlet

Есть сервлет с такой аннотацией @WebServlet("/*"). Когда в методе этого же сервлета вызываю req.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/jsp/pages/contact_list.jsp").forward(req, resp); То по новой вызывается этот же сервлет, а потом уже сервет от JSP. Подскажите как избежать вызов первого сервлета.

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, примерный код того, как вы это делаете. Будет проще вам помочь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

символы `/*` - означают, что действие будет распространяться, на любой адрес, который подходит под маску `/*`, фактически это любой адрес будь-то `/jsp/pages/contact_list.jsp` или какой-либо другой, если вам нужно выполнение сервлета только на одной странице `/`, то вам необходимо изменить аннотацию на `@WebServlet("/")`

Comment: Мне надо реализовать FrontController. Поэтому нужно обрабатывать все запросы в одном сервлете. Но при этом я не могу понять как отправить клиенту JSP.

Comment: `@WebServlet("/")` как раз и задаёт сервлет по умолчанию ("default" servlet). А чтобы привязать сервлет только к странице `/`, надо использовать `@WebServlet("")`.